# Select data.frame rows from specific days of the week

Tags: r, date

I have the following data.frame:

```
           Bounty Snickers Mars
2014-10-02    400      200 1000
2014-10-03    400      100  100
2014-10-04    100      100  500
2014-10-05    800      900  600
2014-10-06    400      300  400
2014-10-07   2000     1500  800
       ...    ...      ...  ...
```

Is there a way to select all rows that fall, for example, on a Monday, or on a weekend?

Comment: Take a look [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009351/removing-weekend-data-in-an-r-dataframe) for weekends and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216138/find-the-day-of-a-week-in-r) for week days. Next time try to use Google first, thanks.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I've Googled for 30min before posting the question using terms such as "R subset by weekday", "R select data on weekend", "R data frame select weekends", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df[format(as.Date(row.names(df)), '%A')=='Monday',]
#         Bounty Snickers Mars
#2014-10-06    400      300  400
```

Or for the `weekend` one option is to use `wday`

```
 library(lubridate)
 df[wday(as.Date(row.names(df))) %in% 6:7,]
 #        Bounty Snickers Mars
 #2014-10-03    400      100  100
 #2014-10-04    100      100  500
```

Comment: You have `wday` in base R too

Comment: @David Arenburg When I try `?wday`, it shows only two options ie. `data.table` and `lubridate`

Comment: See the first answer in the first link I provided in my comment on the question. As I know you, you were already aware of this. I even remember one of your answers using similar approach for hour calculation

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, May be I have to start a fresh console and see if that works.