# R - extending the length of a data frame to be similar to another

Tags: r

I’ve a very unusual solution to the problem below. I wonder is there a better way to approach this?

The problem:
There are 2 data sets stored in two different data frames. 1 of them is a daily balance of product a , while the other is a weekly balance of product b. Due to a request, i need to perform a “union” on the two data frames in order to do a time series visualization. Since product b does not have daily data, the balance will be hold static until the next update.

How do i “expand” table of product b to have the same length as product a table while holding the balance static for days which product b does not have the data?

Table of product A

**Data frame name: TableA**

```
Date (yyyy-mm-dd) / Ccy/ Product /Balance
2019-12-01 / USD / A / 100
2019-12-01 / GBP / A / 100
2019-12-02 / USD / A / 200
2019-12-02 / GBP / A / 150
2019-12-03 / USD / A / 180
2019-12-03 / GBO / A / 210
```

Table of product B

**Data frame name: TableB**

```
Date (yyyy-mm-dd) / Ccy/ Product /Balance
2019-12-01 / USD / B / 100
2019-12-01 / SGD / B / 100
2019-12-03 / USD / B / 180
2019-12-03 / SGD / B / 210
```

My quirky solution below. Do let me know your thoughts and critique. THANK YOU in advance!!

```
library(tidyverse)

unique_dates <- unique(tableA$date)
expanded_tableB <- unique_dates%>%left_join(tableB, by=c(Date=Date))%>% fill(-c(“date”))%>% fill(-c(“date”),.direction=c(“up”))

union_table <- bind_rows(tableA,expanded_tableB)
```

Comment: To clarify, for product "B", you have 2 rows (`Ccy` of `USD` and `SGD`) for each date. Did you want 2 additional balances added for date 2019-12-02 for each of `USD` and `SGD`?

Comment: Hi Ben. Thank you. Yes, 2 additional lines for COB 2019-12-02 from product B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach. If you need additional rows added for missing dates, for both `Ccy` of `SGD` and `USD` for product "B", then would first `group_by` `Ccy`. Use `complete` to fill in dates based on the first and last table found in Table A (based on what you described I believe). Then finally `bind_rows` to add Table A.

```
library(tidyverse)

tableB %>%
  group_by(Ccy) %>%
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(tableA$Date), max(tableA$Date), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(Product, Balance) %>%
  bind_rows(tableA)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Ccy [4]
   Ccy   Date       Product Balance
   <chr> <date>     <chr>     <dbl>
 1 SGD   2019-12-01 B           100
 2 SGD   2019-12-02 B           100
 3 SGD   2019-12-03 B           210
 4 USD   2019-12-01 B           100
 5 USD   2019-12-02 B           100
 6 USD   2019-12-03 B           180
 7 USD   2019-12-01 A           100
 8 GBP   2019-12-01 A           100
 9 USD   2019-12-02 A           200
10 GBP   2019-12-02 A           150
11 USD   2019-12-03 A           180
12 GBO   2019-12-03 A           210
```

**Data**

```
tableA <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-02", "2019-12-02", "2019-12-03", "2019-12-03")),
  Ccy = c("USD", "GBP", "USD", "GBP", "USD", "GBO"),
  Product = "A",
  Balance = c(100, 100, 200, 150, 180, 210),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

tableB <- data.frame(
  Date = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-03", "2019-12-03")),
  Ccy = c("USD", "SGD", "USD", "SGD"),
  Product = "B",
  Balance = c(100, 100, 180, 210),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ben! The data that i have from table A will not have weekend and holiday dates. Do you know if there’s any tweaks that i could do?

Comment: You could filter weekdays through various approaches, see [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009351/remove-weekend-data-in-a-dataframe). You can also filter based on holidays, if you have a separate list of holiday dates, or by other means. For example, one library `RQuantLib` can check if dates are on holidays or give a list of holidays between dates for various calendars/countries. I don't have much experience with this, but does look feasible.

Comment: Thank you so much Ben!